# How do you add data from the database to the shared _Layout.cshtml in ASP.NET Core MVC (.NET 6) application?

Tags: c#, model, asp.net-core-mvc

NET gurus, I am going crazy over here. I have been trying for 3 days already and nothing seems to work. I have created a partial view, a base controller, tried out different functions. Every solution I have found is outdated.

Does anyone know how to do it now in ASP.NET Core .NET 6, MVC with Razor pages? I can't find the right documentation.

I have a menu in my _Layout.cshtml and want to display categories from database there, but the model is always NULL. I have no problem displaying the data in a different view, I just can't seem to add the model to the _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: In razor page,you can still use a partial view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use a [View Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to render the category.

For example, we could refer to the following steps to display category in the MVC application layout page:

1. Create new folder named ViewComponents. In this folder, create new class named CategoryViewComponent.cs as below:

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
   using WebApplication1.Data;

   namespace WebApplication1.ViewComponents
   {
       [ViewComponent(Name ="Category")]
       public class CategoryViewComponent:ViewComponent
       {
           private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
           public CategoryViewComponent(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
           {
               _context = applicationDbContext;
           }

           public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
           {
               return View("Index", _context.Categories.ToList());
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. In Views folder, create new folders with path Views\Shared\Components\Category. In Category folder, create new folder named Index.cshtml:

   ```
   @model List<WebApplication1.Data.Category>

   <h2>Category</h2>

   <ul>
       @foreach(var item in Model)
       {
           <li>@item.CategoryName</li>
       }
   </ul>
   ```
3. Invoke the view component in the _Layout.cshtml page:

   ```
   <div class="container">
       <main role="main" class="pb-3">
           @await Component.InvokeAsync("Category")
           @RenderBody()
       </main>
   </div>
   ```

The file structure as below:

[image: 174275-image.png]

Then, the result is like this:

[image: 174322-image.png]

If using the Razor page application, use the same code and the file structure as below:

[image: 174326-image.png]

Then, the result is like this:

[image: 174344-image.png]

More detail information, you can also refer [View Components in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/view-components).

Answer (score 1):

A layout view can have a typed model. With razor pages I would introduce a base page model;

```cs
interface IViewTemplate{
    IEnumerable<string> GetCategories();
}
public abstract class BasePageModel : PageModel, IViewTemplate{
    ...
}
public class MyPageModel : BasePageModel
    ...
}
```

Then your view can;

```cs
@model IViewTemplate

@foreach(var category in Model.GetCategories()){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!... but since there are is no BasePage in the MVC anymore, shouldn't that be a job of a controller? Am I mistaken?

Comment: Page views do have a `BasePage`, and you can override that with a `@inherits ...`. But I'm talking about page models (eg `@model IndexModel` ... `class IndexModel : ...`).